# Graphql Schema Type

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Can we define the type of followers and following as User? or is it better if I will just create a differenct schema on both following and followers?

```
type User {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        email: String!
        posts: [Post!]
        following: [User]
        followers: [User]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your way is fine and there's nothing wrong with it.** However, if you need more info in those fields you could do something like:

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    posts: [Post!]
    following: [Follower]
    followers: [Follower]
}

type Follower {
   user: User
   dateFollowed: String
}
```

That allows you to reuse the User type while also incorporating additional information related to a follower. Like I said though, if you don't need that extra info then your way works fine. Good luck!

Comment: Alright! thanks for answering!